# Conditional likelihood with missing values

Tags: econometrics, missing-data, likelihood

I want to estimate a logistic regression model on a panel data (subject-time) with subject-fixed effects.

$$\log(p_{it}/(1-p_{it})) = \alpha_{i} + \beta x_{it} + \epsilon_{it}.$$

To do so, I want to maximize the conditional likelihood function to overcome the incidental parameters problem. The specific issue that I face is that within each subject there are some observations that are not collected. I do not know how many are not collected, but I do know that all the observations that are not collected have the outcome variable as 0. Below is a pictorial representation of the context -

[image]

The question I have is, what will be the direction of bias in the coefficient estimated from the collected data, why and, are there any approaches to correct the bias?

Comment: From the way you've described it, I presume that you have no way of distinguishing post-hoc which 0 is an *true* zero and which one is a missing value, correct?

Comment: Hi Durden, apologies for the late reply. Among the observed records, that is, the first three boxes in the picture, I can say that box 2 is a True zero. I cannot comment on the boxes in gray are they are not observed. Any thoughts will be very helpful.